# Firefox - How to view network request that opens new window

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to debug (someone else's) site where there is a button that opens a new browser window that leads to a 404. I am trying to determine if the new window is opened with a POST, but the old window's dev network tools don't show the request since it occurs in a new window. And when I open the dev tools in the new window, the request has already been made and doesn't show up.

How do I view this network request in the dev tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), beware it's not the same as the *Web Console*.
From there, you'll be able to monitor all Requests made from all contexts, by switching-on the "Requests" toggle.

[image: screenshot of the Browser Console]

Comment: Hey thanks, I had no idea the browser console had a request toggle!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy to view the traffic.

or

> Maybe I should introduce you to my main man, <del>Edgar</del> Charles!

https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tools to edit the HTML from their site so that the link opens in the same page, then you get all the network information you'd expect.

1. Open up developer tools, at the top left click the icon of a rectangle with a cursor entering it from the bottom right, its tool tip is "Pick an element from the page".
2. Click on the link you're interested in on  the page itself.
3. In the 'Inspector' tab of developer tools, find the anchor tag for the link you want to edit.
4. Right click the HTML and select edit as HTML from the context menu.
5. Delete the target="_blank" attribute.
6. Just click on the link as you would normally and all the information will appear in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) window:

> 1. From the three lines (hamburger) menu in Firefox's upper right, select the **More Tools** submenu, and then select **Browser Console**.
> 2. From the keyboard: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or
>    <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on a Mac).

2. If there is a *Browser Console Mode* bar across the top, select **Multiprocess (Slower)**.
3. In the top right select **Requests**.
4. From the gear icon menu in the top right, choose **Enable Network Monitoring**.

[Firefox Browser console window showing settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN0qI.png)

Note:  This answer expands on the earlier answer by [kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido), with thanks to [Yay295](https://superuser.com/users/418088/yay295) on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1411992/how-to-view-log-of-network-requests-across-tabs-in-firefox) for additional information.